# Linux Bash "|" operator doesn't work - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I am trying to check user password via login command like this:

```
# echo "name\npassword" | login
```

but the command ends without writing anything. `echo` ends because of SIGPIPE.
Why did `login` stop before asking for name and password?

When I do the same with `passwd` command, it works:

```
# echo "password\npassword" | passwd  
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and Bash 4.2.25

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The login command reads input from the terminal instead of accepting it as input via pipe (STDIN).

If you want to script `login` you can use the `expect` utility:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn "login"

expect "login:" { send "mtak\r" }
expect "Password:" { send "mypassword\r" }

interact
```

Paste this in a file, run `chmod +x script.ex` and run it with `./script.ex`

Comment: NICE!  Thanks for this.  I've been looking for an interactive solution for some other scripts and prefer `expect` to the boring `read`.  +1 for sure